# Espressomatch ExposedDropdownMenu

Tags: android, android-espresso

how to match  ExposedDropdownMenu from espresso , I want the first item , but onview nor ondata work

```
   <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/textField_driver_title"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:hint="@string/driver_title_hint"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/brown_grey"
                    app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                    app:errorEnabled="true"
                    app:hintTextColor="@color/brown_grey"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    
                    <AutoCompleteTextView
                        android:id="@+id/editText_driver_title"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="none"
                        android:lines="1" />
    
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```